# Using Capybara w/ Selenium, how would I click a table row?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara

Would simply like to know if there's an alternative to click_link / click_button that can be used with any element as some of my clickable elements are not standard html clickables such as tr elements, but they still contain href attributes.

Javascript enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Javascript then:

```
page.execute_script("$('whatever_you_want').click()");
```

Comment: This gives me the **Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError** error message.

Comment: @cyle That means you driver doesn't support javascript. Make sure you are using a driver that supports it; like Selenium or Webkit

Comment: I'm using Selenium... probably something off on my end though.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same situation with a html month view, I had to choose a day of month. I kept it as simple as I could and this is only one way of doing this.

```
# Choose July 22 (at this point in time)
assert page.has_css? '#calendar'
within '#calendar' do
  find('td', :text => '22').click 
end
```

Comment: I prefer this method to directly calling javascript. I'm sure everyone uses jQuery (or similar), but using capybara methods makes for more robust and readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using cucumber? Not sure if it's any use to you, but here's a cucumber step definition for clicking anything with selenium:

```
Then /^I click "(.+)"$/ do |locator|
  selenium.click locator
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the javascript solution in past, it works in the sense that the button do gets clicked, but cucumber fails to recognise it as a completed step.